# How can I add specific point on boxplot in ggplot2 in different colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with two columns variable and value:

```
df<- data.frame(c(rep('v1',4),rep('v2',4)),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
colnames(df) <- c('variable', 'value')
```

Next I make a boxplot with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
j <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(variable), value)) 
j + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")
```

My problem now is to add with **geom_point** specific points which were not present in the original dataframe to v1 and v2 boxplots in different (red) colour. How can I do it?

Comment: Check out this post. I think this is exactly what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255739/how-would-you-plot-a-box-plot-and-specific-points-on-the-same-plot

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried before. Now your solution with an additional dataframe made it really nice and simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer and giving it an up arrow

Comment: I would love to but unfortunately, I'm a fresh user here so I don't have enough points to vote but it says that they recorded my vote for you. Sorry, I can't do more... Thanks for the help again:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think this might be what you want.

```
df<- data.frame(c(rep('v1',4),rep('v2',4)),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
colnames(df) <- c('variable', 'value')
df2 <- data.frame(c(rep('v1',4),rep('v2',4)),c(2,5,6,1,2,3,5,3))
colnames(df2) <- c('variable', 'value')


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(variable), value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free") +
  geom_point(data = df2,aes(x=variable, y=value),color = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank! It is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a point to both facets then see the example here:

```
library(ggplot2)
j <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(variable), value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +  
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")

j  + 
  geom_point(aes(x=1, y=2), col="red", size=3)+
  geom_point(aes(x=1, y=2.5), col="green", size=3)
```

[image]